# Move data in the same Activity

Tags: java, android

In my app i retrieve some data from Json that i stored in String Yesterday Today and Tomorrow, now the problem i need that data will be the title of my tabs. It all make part of the same activity and i can't use Intent or Bundle for take and send it.

```
...other stuff

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0){
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
            //faccio una richiesta al server e attendo risposta
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url); 
            Log.e("RAW-JSON: ","Retrieve RAW-Json is "+jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    String DATESTRING = jsonObj.getString("date");

                    JSONObject DATE = new JSONObject(DATESTRING); //Log.d("STAMPA","DATESTRING"+DATESTRING);

                    //Log.d("PER FAVORE","IERI ERA "+Ieri);
                    //ESTRAGGO E INSERISCO DOVE MI SERVE
                    String Yesterday = DATE.getString("ieri");
                    String Today = DATE.getString("oggi");
                    String Tomorrow = DATE.getString("domani");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Errore nel recupero dati",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //tolgo il caricamento di pDialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new YesterdayFragment(),Yesterday );  //i can set from here the name of tabs but how if the name from by Json?
        adapter.addFragment(new TodayFragment(), Today);
        adapter.addFragment(new TomorrowFragment(), Tomorrow);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: Just make them class variables instead of only creating them inside `doInBackground`.

Comment: Could you make me an example?

Comment: Yes Trusted , declare your variables in Class Level Scope , actually @csmckelvey said right. You can check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your variables in Class Level Scope . **Define inside your class , outside of any method or code block,**

```
  String Yesterday , Today , Tomorrow = " ; //Define inside your class , outside of any method or code block,

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0){
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
            //faccio una richiesta al server e attendo risposta
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url); 
            Log.e("RAW-JSON: ","Retrieve RAW-Json is "+jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    String DATESTRING = jsonObj.getString("date");

                    JSONObject DATE = new JSONObject(DATESTRING); //Log.d("STAMPA","DATESTRING"+DATESTRING);

                    //Log.d("PER FAVORE","IERI ERA "+Ieri);
                    //ESTRAGGO E INSERISCO DOVE MI SERVE
                    Yesterday = DATE.getString("ieri");
                    Today = DATE.getString("oggi");
                   Tomorrow = DATE.getString("domani");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Errore nel recupero dati",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //tolgo il caricamento di pDialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new YesterdayFragment(),Yesterday );  //i can set from here the name of tabs but how if the name from by Json?
        adapter.addFragment(new TodayFragment(), Today);
        adapter.addFragment(new TomorrowFragment(), Tomorrow);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: Wait i make a mistake

Comment: yeah i updated the answer, 


      String Yesterday , Today , Tomorrow = " ; //Define inside your class , outside of any method or code block,

Comment: we need to initialize the values of these strings for inital reference with "" (empty string) ,

Comment: Run but don't write nothing

Comment: yes it will set the tab values , when your api call will update your String value

Comment: where you are getting your json , you need to update these values there. so it will reflect into the tabs

Comment: How could i make? I'm really new to Android world and Java